# Cannot make Gregwar/Image working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image-caching

I installed the Gregwar/Image package ( https://github.com/Gregwar/Image ) to laravel, I changed the caching directory to `$cacheDir = '/public/cache/images/';`, I can generate cached image in `php artisan tinker`, but when I use it in blade template or controller I get the `http://localhost/testsite/public/cache/images//f/a/l/l/b/fallback.jpg` error url instead, I have narrowed down the problem to: `Gregwar\Image\Adapter\GD` and this function:

```
    protected function openJpeg($file)
    {
        if (file_exists($file) && filesize($file)) {
            $this->resource = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
        } else {
            $this->resource = false;
        }
    }
```

code used in blade:

```
<div class="faceted_objects thumbnail_container" data-url="/pictures/album/test_324716/sorted/new/page/1/">

    <?php

    use Gregwar\Image\Image;

    echo Image::open('public/storage/uploads/images/picture/1/bacon-broccoli-egg-bites21.jpg', 'transparent', 'center', 'center')
        ->zoomCrop(100, 100)
        ->jpeg();

    ?>

    {{--{{ gregwar_image( 100, 100, 'zoomCrop', 'picture/1/bacon-broccoli-egg-bites21.jpg' ) }}--}}

    {!! $image->getOtherImages() !!}

</div>
```

the code inside `if (file_exists($file) && filesize($file)) {` never runs and `filesize()` returns NOTHING using `print_r` or `dd()`, I have no idea how to fix this, the weird thing is it works in `php artisan tinker` but NOT on the actual site

[image: works in <code>php artisan tinker</code> so why does not work in blade template?]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the real path to avoid any issues. Use `realpath($imagePath)`.

When you access your project from `CLI`, the path of execution is your project root folder.

When you access it from the `WEB` (fpm), the path of execution is `{project}/public` folder, the one declared in the `vhost` configuration.

Comment: I used the path `'public/storage/uploads/images/picture/1/bacon-broccoli-egg-bites21.jpg'` but it still returns `cache/images/f/a/l/l/b/fallback.jpg`

Comment: @yeln try to dump `$file` right before `filesize($file)` and post the result

Comment: `var_dump($file)` gives `string(70) "public/storage/uploads/images/picture/1/bacon-broccoli-egg-bites21.jpg"`

Comment: remove the `public/` at the start of the image path CLI

Comment: I see, it seems to be working now without `public/`, why is `public/` the problem though?